# Laptop DVD Drive Hacking

Tags: dvd

I'm trying to hack the firmware on my laptop's DVD drive since it's useless to me and I'm going to replace it with a HDD caddy so I might as well have some fun with it.

The only information I know about the drive is "GUE1N", there is no manufacturer info anywhere.

I tried devilsclaws lg renesas drive utility but it hangs on starting dumping process (and cannot be closed anymore, task manager says access denied for some reason)

Does anyone know if I can dump the firmware directly from the drive? (at least via the ATA port it is connected to)

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe your looking for something like this: https://github.com/devilsclaw/flasher

Comment: That's the exact tool that I already tried but it hangs on "starting dumping process" unfortunately

Comment: Have you tried both versions (32bit and 64 bit) and have you run the tool as administrator? The tool hasn't seen any updates in a while and maybe your drive is too new for this method to work. Nevertheless the possibilities of tools like this are always very limited. In most cases you need direct access to the hardware and have to solder some ports on the drive board to a RS232 or something similar to be able to dump a firmware. I doesn't seem like something to do just to "have fun". Also what features/limits does the drive have that need to be hacked?